# How to use search option in Powershell HTML output

Tags: html, powershell

I want to convert powershell output into HTML format with the search option. 
I have HTML with jscript/css which i am trying to add into HTML style in my Powershell code. 
The search option is not searching data in page.

HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want this html format table to get output of command
Get-service.

```
$services = Get-Service

$FullHTML = $services | select Name,StartType -First 5 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Comment: Here is the sample link for HTML code
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Replace the entire <table>...</table> section in your HTML with "$table" (no quotes)
2. Save the code to a text file, say, template.txt

Then you can run the following to produce a searchable HTML page:

```
$template = Get-Content ".\template.txt" -Raw
$table = (Get-Service | select Name,StartType | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment).Replace('<table>', '<table id="myTable">')
$template.Replace("`$table", $table) | Out-File .\Services.html
```